# How to pass data into my app through using qr code?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to embed some data in qr code as a uri, which when I scan the qr code, my android app will be launched automatically and also display my data in the app.
I have already done the scan and launch part, but I don't know how to get the data from uri. What format and coding should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a library which can help you with the formats you need as per your requirement.

[Barcode Scanner (ZXing)](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/387)

You should put more information or code to your question.